# Can I set the type of a field within a class at runtime to a newly created type in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, reflection.emit, typebuilder

I'm using `Reflection.Emit` and `TypeBuilder` to create a new type at runtime. My setup is something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    public object MyField = CreateInstanceOfNewType();
    public MyClass() {}
}
```

The issue is that `MyClass.MyField` is declared with type `object` and so the implicit cast operators that exist for the new type are not called when castable types are assigned to `MyClass.MyField`. Is there a way to set the type of the field to the newly created type so that it behaves similarly to how it would in the typical case?

Comment: Would the type implement a known interface? If so, simply assign the *object* to a variable typed as that interface.

Comment: Implicit cast operators can't be defined in interfaces though. This does get around the type changing on assignment but won't allow the use of implicit casts.

Comment: Please describe your actual business problem then, instead of this unworkable solution for an unknown problem. You are correct - C# des not allow this solution to work. That doesn't mean that your problem is unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the exact use case, a possible solution is to make your class generic, then use reflection to create a static generic method that creates an instance of the class. This allows you to use the variable dynamic type when declaring your property:

```
public class MyClass<T> { 
public T MyField = CreateInstanceOfNewType<T≥(); 
public MyClass() {} 
}

public static MyClass<T> createClass<T>() {
return new MyClass<T>:
}

dynamic instanceOfMyClass = typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("createClass").MakeGeneric(dynamicType).Invoke()
```

Another alternative is using the dynamic keyword.

Comment: When I use `dynamic`, it just behaves the same as if I use `object`. When I try to assign another type it just takes on the new type instead of forcing an implicit cast.

Comment: What type does your createinstanceofclass return?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you want to *initialize* an object of your new type with an object of some castable type you've built an implicit cast operator for. I would suggest that instead of implicit operators you consider using constructors: use `Reflection.Emit` to create constructors that take one parameter of your castable types and use that parameter value to initialize the object of the new type. You want to have same result as this piece of code would do:

```
public class MyNewType
{
    public MyNewType(CastableType value)
    {
        /* implement initialization with value */
    }

    /* other stuff */
}
```

You can then use [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, params object[] arguments)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) to make use of that constructor. Here's an example:

```
var newType = GetNewType();
var castableObject = CreateInstanceOfCastableType();
this.MyField = Activator.CreateInstance(newType, castableObject);
```